# "Nearest neighbor graph" - official name?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

Simple terminology: Assume you have a metric or whatnot that defines a "neighbor" relation on a point set. Connect all next neighbors with an edge to get a graph. Does this graph have a special name? "Nearest neighbor graph" is the official name (Wiki article exists) in the case of metric, but I rather have a whatnot :-), so I'm reluctant to use it. (Whatnot=here: the coordinate axis parallel rectangle defined by the two points in question is empty)

Comment: sense of please your question, . Sorry, I can't rephrase make

Comment: Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28discrete_mathematics%29#Graph) the set of edges is the "adjacency relation". So maybe you'd be understood if you wrote "the adjacency relation is that two points are related if the coordinate axis parallel rectangle defined by them is empty". But I am not a graph theorist and maybe there's a more common way of phrasing this sort of thing.

Comment: Sounds legit, THX for the tip.